# Test xamarin app on real ios device from windows without connecting device to mac

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, deployment, device

I have:

1. Windows 10 + VS2019 CE
2. iPhone 6
3. Remote Mac (without ability to connect to it my iphone!)
   I made all setup and i can test my application on emulator in VS2019 CE on Windows. But, how to test my app on real iPhone device?
   **WARNING! I have no ability to connect my iPhone to remote mac (over USB or someting else).**
   and I hope that the opportunity still exist.
   Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to run the application without connnecting to mac.

1. Use [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) , we can deploy the app to the real device on windows, but it has some limitations , check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations .
2. [Create ipa  file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos) and then install on the real device , it requires Distribution Provisioning Profile and we can choose **Ad Hoc Testing**(in this way  the `udid` of the real device should be added in Provisioning Profile) or **In House / Enterprise Deployment**.